# Meaning of absolute value in squareroot

Tags: calculus

Recently I've encountered this problem:

[$y = \sqrt{x}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkD2A.png)

[$y = \sqrt{|x|}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wO0t.png)

We all know $\sqrt{-x}$ is invalid so this is quite confusing to use $\sqrt{|x|}$. Is |absolute| being used here to "legalize" a negative number being under a square root?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: $\sqrt{-x}$ is fine for $x\leq 0$

Comment: Yes, you could think that the absolute value function is used there to make it possible for $x$ to assume negatives values. So, the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ is the entire real line whereas the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is only $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{|x|}$ are two different functions. On $[0,\infty)$, the two functions return the same value, bot on $(-\infty, 0)$, only the second function is defined.

There is nothing "better" or "legal" about the second function. They are different, but not better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

The graphs are similar however for the absolute value the negative half of the graph is a reflection of the positive x-axis.